# What's preventing an Ionic Segment with dynamic value from working when nested in an async container?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working at a page with multiple `<ion-segment>` elements, some of which nested into `async` containers.
Those ones do not get initialised correctly and the selected `<ion-segment-button>` does not get highlighted as it should unless the initial value is hardcoded.

See example below:

## HTML file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Segment Bug Test</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-segment
    [value]="segmentA$ | async"
    (ionChange)="updateSegmentA($event.detail.value!)"
  >
    <ion-segment-button value="A-1">
      <ion-label>segment A-1</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="A-2">
      <ion-label>segment A-2</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  <p class="ion-text-center">segment A value = "{{ segmentA$.value }}"</p>
  <hr />
  <div *ngIf="observable$ | async as dataSource; else noData">
    <ion-segment
      [value]="segmentB"
      (ionChange)="updateSegmentB($event.detail.value!)"
    >
      <ion-segment-button value="B-1">
        <ion-label>segment B-1</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="B-2">
        <ion-label>segment B-2</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    <p class="ion-text-center">segment B value = "{{ segmentB }}"</p>
    <hr />
    <ion-segment value="default">
      <ion-segment-button value="default">
        <ion-label>Default</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="segment">
        <ion-label>Segment</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <ng-template #noData>
    <p class="ion-text-center">No data to display</p>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

## TS file (extract)

```
  segmentA$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('A-1');
  observable$ = new Observable<any>();
  segmentB = 'B-1';

  constructor() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  updateSegmentA(value: SegmentValue) {
    this.segmentA$.next(value as string);
  }

  updateSegmentB(value: SegmentValue) {
    this.segmentB = value as string;
  }

  private fetchData() {
    let option: string;
    this.observable$ = this.segmentA$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap((o) => (option = o)),
      delay(1000),
      map(() => option),
    );
  }
```

See full example on [GitHub](https://github.com/leomazza/ionic-segment-bug) or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/leomazza/ionic-segment-bug).

I tried using `[(ngModel)]` or `BehaviorSubject` with `async` pipe without avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some bug due to state of the internal variable of ionic, as a temporary workaround, you can use the below method!

If needed do raise a bug on the ionic github page!
I am triggering change detection manually and toggling the property for `[value]` binding so that the changes will get detected by the component!

ts

```
import { AsyncPipe, CommonModule, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonLabel,
  IonSegment,
  IonSegmentButton,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  SegmentValue, } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, distinctUntilChanged, tap, delay, map,finalize } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe, IonContent, IonHeader, IonLabel, IonSegment, IonSegmentButton, IonTitle, IonToolbar, CommonModule],
})
export class HomePage {
  segmentA$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('A-1');
  observable$ = new Observable<any>();
  segmentB = '';

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  updateSegmentA(value: SegmentValue) {
    this.segmentA$.next(value as string);
  }

  updateSegmentB(value: SegmentValue) {
    this.segmentB = value as string;
  }

  private fetchData() {
    let option: string;
    this.observable$ = this.segmentA$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap((o) => (option = o)),
      delay(1000),
      map(() => option),
      tap(() => {
        this.bugWorkAround();
      })
    );
  }

  bugWorkAround() {
    this.segmentB = '';
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.segmentB = 'B-1';
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
    })
  }
}
```

html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Segment Bug Test</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-segment
    [value]="segmentA$ | async"
    (ionChange)="updateSegmentA($event.detail.value!)"
  >
    <ion-segment-button value="A-1">
      <ion-label>segment A-1</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="A-2">
      <ion-label>segment A-2</ion-label>
    </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
  <p class="ion-text-center">segment A value = "{{ segmentA$.value }}"</p>
  <hr />
  <div *ngIf="(observable$ | async) as dataSource; else noData">
    <ion-segment
      [value]="segmentB"
      (ionChange)="updateSegmentB($event.detail.value!)"
    >
      <ion-segment-button value="B-1">
        <ion-label>segment B-1</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="B-2">
        <ion-label>segment B-2</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
    <p class="ion-text-center">segment B value = "{{ segmentB }}"</p>
    <hr />
    <ion-segment value="default">
      <ion-segment-button value="default">
        <ion-label>Default</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="segment">
        <ion-label>Segment</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <ng-template #noData
    ><p class="ion-text-center">No data to display</p></ng-template
  >
</ion-content>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/%7E/github.com/leomazza/ionic-segment-bug)

Comment: Thanks for you help :)
I modified your function slightly to trigger the workaround just once.
```
private bugWorkAround() {
    if (!this.isInitialised) {
      this.segmentB = '';
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.segmentB = 'B-1';
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      });
      this.isInitialised = true;

Comment: I raised a [bug report on Ionic's GitHub page](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/28816)